# Order of rows shown changes on selection of columns from dependent pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why does the order of rows displayed differ, when I take a subset of the dataframe columns to display, via show?

Here is the original dataframe:

[image]

Here dates are in the given order, as you can see, via show.

Now the order of rows displayed via show changes when I select a subset of predict_df by method of column selection for a new dataframe.[image]

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. Row ordering is not deterministic.

Comment: What on earth a Close for?

Comment: So I simulated this and looked with glom and found that for a small dataset the position with partition was the same - refuting @mck - but that the show indeed does show sometimes different ordering of both the dataframes. Has to be in the show implementation.

Comment: @mck is correct - dataframes are unordered until you explicitly do the orderBy on specific column(s). `show` is showing the first N rows, but the definition of "first" will changes because of lack of order

Comment: @AlexOtt  So, how is it that with glom I can get exact same ordering within partitions then?

Comment: It's a good question as running with and without cache I get same or differing order  .cache on orderBy / sort. When I look at glom I get the same elements in same order within partitions. The GUI for Jobs run etc. I always find hard to read, but if you cache - as you gave two actions - it will be fine. Somehow I cannot get it 100% tied.

Comment: @thebluephantom it may depend on the source that is used to produce partitions - like, when you read from CSV file, records will be ordered by order in file. But it's not guaranteed for every source.  It's the same as in SQL databases - when you do `select * from table` the order of rows isn't guaranteed, and may depend on the underlying storage implementation, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt  Being a little older I always assume no guaranteed ordering of data. But Spark is not a DB. When I add the .cache I get the same. Could also be that Catalyst does not do the right optimzation. I will look at the second answer now.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have furnished you with the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Because of Spark dataframe itself is unordered. It's due to parallel processing principles wich Spark uses. Different records may be located in different files (and on different nodes) and different executors may read the data in different time and in different sequence.

So You have to excplicitly specify order in Spark action using `orderBy` (or `sort`) method. E.g.:

```
df.orderBy('date').show()
```

In this case result will be ordered by `date` column and would be more predictible. But, if many records have equal `date` value then within those `date` subset records also would be unordered. So in this case, in order to obtain strongly ordered data, we have to perform `orderBy` on set of columns. And values in all rows of those set of columns must be unique. E.g.:

```
df.orderBy(col("date").asc, col("other_column").desc)
```

In general unordered datasets is a normal case for data processing systems. Even "traditional" DBMS like `PostgeSQL` or `MS SQL Server` in general return unordered records and we have to explicitly use `ORDER BY` clause in `SELECT` statement. And even if sometime we may see the same results of one query it isn't guarenteed by DBMS that by another execution result will be the same also. Especially if data reading is performed on a large amout of data.

Comment: Why when i do glom on a 2 dfs i fef exact same order of data in partitions?

Comment: I didn't use `glom` in practice, but I think there are large architectural differenceies between `glom` and `Spark`.  `glom` is a local data processing library, whereas `Spark` is a distributed data processing framework. `glom` is much simpler and processes the data in simpler and more predictable way.

Comment: For example, `Spark` breaks data processing action into several tasks that run simultaneously and simultaneously read the data from different partitions (files). Then data obtained by different executors are collected by Spark application driver and portions from different executors could be combined in different (and not predictable) order.

Comment: I mean with glom to inspect the partitions. That's all. Please, I've got a few clues.

Comment: In general unordered datasets is a normal case for data processing systems (see update to my answer). If You obtain the same results using `glom` it may be the random result. You have to investigate `glom` documentation whether `glom` guarrantee the same results or not. I think not :)

Answer (score 1):

The situation occurs because the `show` is an `action` that is called *twice*.

As no `.cache` is applied the whole cycle starts again from the start. Moreover, I tried this a few times and got the same order and not the same order as the questioner observed. Processing is non-deterministic.

As soon as I used `.cache`, the same result was always gotten.

This means that there is ordering preserved over a narrow transformation on a dataframe, if caching has been applied, otherwise the 2nd action will invoke processing from the start again - the basics are evident here as well. And may be the bottom line is always do ordering explicitly - if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ihor Konovalenko and @mck mentioned, Sprk dataframe is unordered by its nature. Also, looks like your dataframe doesn’t have a reliable key to order, so one solution is using monotonically_increasing_id https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html to create id and that will keep your dataframe always ordered. However if your dataframe is big, be aware this function might take some time to generate id for each row.

Comment: Also not convinced. Do you know what glom is?

Comment: @pltc But does `monotonically_increasing_id` function gurrantee the same id's for records in different runs? Documentation don't say this.

Comment: @thebluephantom I do. So in your test above, do you test it on a cluster or you test in local machine? how many executors have you used? how many files does it read from? how many partitions the dataframe is created?

Comment: @Ihor Konovalenko I never try running it twice and compare to be honest. However isn’t ID something that don’t change, and we should capture it only one time and save it?

Comment: Not to mention, OP was looking for a way to keep records order, so the meaning of ID doesn’t really matter. As long as the current record has smaller ID than the next record (that’s how `monotonically_increasing_id` supposed to work), then we should be fine

Comment: Databricks community edition, is good enough for this test.

Comment: @thebluephantom Databricks community edition free version has only one cluster, one worker, so it’s enough for this test, but the same result is not guaranteed to be the same in different environment, especially in multi workers or complex cluster

Comment: You can see it how you want, look at my answer. That's how I see it, it is basic.